# How to develop Apps for AWS SQS using Kotlin

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-sqs

I'm looking for newest AWS SQS libraries written in Kotlin for Android. What do you use in your projects to find the right solution?
... or you could solve the problem using libraries written in Java?:)

Greetings

Comment: WHy would anyone want to close this valid question>?

Comment: Because in statue -> stackoverflow is not for recommendations, maybe I change it for solution or problem and it will be +1? :)

Answer (score 0):

AWS now offers the new **AWS SDK for Kotlin**. You can build Native Android apps (and other Kotlin Apps) using this SDK. This SDK has support for AWS Services such as SNS. SQS, S3, and so on.

You can find the DEV guide here:

[AWS SDK for Kotlin Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html)

To learn how to use this SDK, see .

[Get started with the SDK for Kotlin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html)

**Update**

As per your comment, I am updating this answer. First, the Kotlin SDK does not have a Builder as part of the Service Client. To perform a SQS operation using Kotlin, you can use syntax like this:

```
suspend fun sendMessages(queueUrlVal: String, message: String) {
    println("Sending multiple messages")
    println("\nSend message")
    val sendRequest = SendMessageRequest {
        queueUrl = queueUrlVal
        messageBody = message
        delaySeconds = 10
    }

    SqsClient { region = "us-east-1" }.use { sqsClient ->
        sqsClient.sendMessage(sendRequest)
        println("A single message was successfully sent.")
    }
}
```

If you want to use the Kotlin SDK in an Android project, which works very well, you need to handle creds properly. I have used a StaticCredentialsProvider provider and it works fine:

```
val staticCredentials = StaticCredentialsProvider {
            accessKeyId = "<Enter key>"
            secretAccessKey = "<Enter key>"
        }
```

Comment: unfortunately it is not clear from documentation how to initialize credentials or credentialsProvider in Android using Kotlin. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73854349/how-to-implement-aws-sqs-in-android 
It doesn't work using example from documentation and other solution does not work at all. For example There is not SQSClientBuilder class. 
         val sqs = SQSClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
            .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
            .build()

Comment: The Kotlin SDK does not have a Builder as part of the SDK.  I will update my answer.