# How to implement AWS SQS in Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin

```
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.sqs.SqsClient
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.sqs.model.CreateQueueRequest
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.sqs.model.GetQueueUrlRequest
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.sqs.model.QueueAttributeName
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.sqs.model.SetQueueAttributesRequest


object AWSSQSManager {
    suspend fun createQueue(queueNameVal: String): String {

      
        println("Create Queue")
        val createQueueRequest = CreateQueueRequest {
            queueName = queueNameVal
        }
        SqsClient { region = "eu-west-1" }.use { sqsClient ->
            sqsClient
                .createQueue(createQueueRequest)
            println("Get queue url")

            val getQueueUrlRequest = GetQueueUrlRequest {
                queueName = queueNameVal
            }

            val getQueueUrlResponse = sqsClient.getQueueUrl(getQueueUrlRequest)
            return getQueueUrlResponse.queueUrl.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
    implementation "aws.sdk.kotlin:sqs:0.17.1-beta"
```

error

```
    aws.sdk.kotlin.runtime.auth.credentials.CredentialsProviderException: No credentials could be loaded from the chain: CredentialsProviderChain -> EnvironmentCredentialsProvider -> ProfileCredentialsProvider -> StsWebIdentityProvider -> EcsCredentialsProvider -> ImdsCredentialsProvider
        at aws.sdk.kotlin.runtime.auth.credentials.CredentialsProviderChain$getCredentials$chainException$1.invoke(CredentialsProviderChain.kt:36)
        at aws.sdk.kotlin.runtime.auth.credentials.CredentialsProviderChain$getCredentials$chainException$1.invoke(CredentialsProviderChain.kt:36)
```

How to use `awscredentials.json` file I have created it manually and how to implement these chain, content, credentialsprovider to apply

```
{
  "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "MYID",
  "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "MYKEY",
  "AWS_REGION": "eu-west-1"
}
```

I've used this guide.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/kotlin_sqs_code_examples.html

```
             * The AWS credentials provider to use for authenticating requests. If not provided a
             * [aws.sdk.kotlin.runtime.auth.credentials.DefaultChainCredentialsProvider] instance will be used.
             * NOTE: The caller is responsible for managing the lifetime of the provider when set. The SDK
             * client will not close it when the client is closed.
             */
            public var credentialsProvider: CredentialsProvider? = null
```

This is my approach still doesn't work:

```
        SqsClient {
            credentialsProvider =
                ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName = "myprofile").also { region = "eu-west-1" }
        }
```

I have configured my profile and it appears in .aws/config and credentials

```
aws configure --profile "myprofile"
```

still error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    aws.sdk.kotlin.runtime.auth.credentials.ProviderConfigurationException: could not find source profile myprofile
        at aws.sdk.kotlin.runtime.auth.credentials.profile
```

Comment: You should almost never bundle AWS credentials with a mobile app. Ideally, the client would authenticate to a back-end (e.g. Amplify with Cognito) and in return receive temporary credentials, or the back-end would make AWS requests on behalf of the authenticated client.

Comment: User is authenticated with other platform seperated from AWS, I have credentials from backend, but I'm not sure how exactly use it. Do you know how to solve it? IMO i do not need any other libraries. Only what I have implemented -> SQS. I do not need amplify.

Comment: The question is how to apply credentials to SqsClient in Kotlin, there is no such thing in documentation.. I edited my post to show what I need.

Comment: The Kotlin docs are quite painful, it seems. In addition to region, provide `credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(...)`. Java example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html#credentials-explicit).

Comment: I can't use this class Unresolved reference: AWSStaticCredentialsProvider, thanks for asnwer

Comment: Ah, perhaps it's called [StaticCredentialsProvider](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-kotlin/blob/230751e55e50afe97c263bcf2698202b959a18b0/aws-runtime/aws-config/common/src/aws/sdk/kotlin/runtime/auth/credentials/StaticCredentialsProvider.kt) in the Kotlin SDK?

Comment: You have saved my day. Yes. It load it, but unfortunately still some issues:
aws.sdk.kotlin.services.sqs.model.SqsException: Access to the resource https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied. I put accesKey, access, secret access and region.

Comment: Do the IAM policies associated with those static AWS credentials allow SQS actions?

Comment: Hmm I think problem is here I need to specify parameter -> queueUrlVal, which in my case IMO is "https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/" which could be wrong? Not sure. Im trying to send message now with this error: https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360354/get-aws-sqs-queue-url

Comment: Thank you very much. It didn't crash and should work. I will investigate it deeply tomorrow. Greetings